# How do I move the boulder in the labyrinth for the game Cave Story

Tags: cave-story

I've looked around the labyrinth quite a bit and I can't figure out how to move the boulder in the final room. When I go in the room and check the boulder, it says I might be able to move it with the help of someone else.

Just outside of that room is a teleporter that doesn't work. There is another room earlier in the labyrinth filled with nice creatures and another broken teleporter. I can't seem to successfully do anything in any of those rooms.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little past that room with the friendly creatures (I'm assuming it's the shop with the friendly Gaudi in it), and down in the right-hand corner is a small "Camp" area with a doctor, a nurse, and Curly resting on a bed. The doctor will give you the clinic key and ask that you go get some medicine from the clinic (they've been chased out by a "ghost").

As you exit the camp, the upper left corner of the screen is where you should look for the clinic. If you took the Machine Gun earlier, and have it up to level 3, boosting up there by shooting downwards is the easiest way to get up. Otherwise, you'll have to do a few tricky jumps to get up. Fight off the monster in the clinic (the blade is wonderful here), obtain the medicine, and head back down to the camp to give it to the doctor. Once you get to that room with the boulder again, Curly will join you, and I don't really want to spoil what happens next.

If you're going for the "best" ending, and haven't taken the machine gun, make sure you don't take the item the professor offers you in that room before the final one with the broken teleporter, though.

Comment: Apparently I never went back to talk to Curly and doc before trying to move the boulder.

Comment: I did the same thing my first time through.

Comment: Specifically, you have to talk to both of them -- I talked to the Doctor and left, and it wasn't enough; I had to go back and talk to Curly

Comment: I am stuck here... I talked to everyone, I took the medicine (even before reaching the boulder) but the girl won't appear there to help me. I simply don't know what to do.